# record not added to model when i call save() on a new record in Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember-Data 0.13-59 & Ember 1.0.0 RC 6 (from starter kit)

**Problem:** upon `save()` to a new record made from `App.Userstat.createRecord({ ... })` the server gets the `POST` and successfully returns an `id` but the new record is not available in the `Userstat` model.

To better understand example: this is a quiz app(for multiple choice questions). Each question has several choices and when a user selects a choice, their choice to the corresponding question is stored in a Model, `App.Userstat`.

At each question, the app needs to know whether the user has already answered this question or if it's new.

I use a computed property as a `setter` and `getter`. The `setter` is called when a user selects a choice (the choice's value is passed to computed property). First it checks if a record exists for the user's current question. If it doesn't exist it will create a new record. If it does exist, it should only issue a `PUT` request with updated content.

**Code Updated(July 8, 11AM)**

```
App.UserstatsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "userstats",

  chosen = function(key, value) {
    // getter
    if(value === undefined) {

       // something goes here

    // setter
    } else {

      // the question.id is used to compare for an existing record in Userstat mdoel
      var questionId = this.get('id');
      var questionModel = this.get('model');

      // does any Userstat record belong to the current question??
      var stats = this.get('controllers.Userstats');
      var stat = stats.get('model').findProperty('question.id', questionId);

      // if no record exists for stat, means user has not answered this question yet...
      if(!stat) {

        newStat = App.Userstat.createRecord({
          "question" : questionModel,
          "choice" : value       // value passed to the computed property
        )}

        newStat.save();                     // I've tried this
        // newStat.get('store').commit();   // and this
        return value;

      // if there is a record(stat) then we will just update the user's choice
      } else {
        stat.set('choice', value);
        stat.get('store').commit();
        return value;
    }
  }.property('controllers.Userstats')
```

No matter how many times I set `chosen` it always sends a `POST` (as opposed to an update only sending a PUT request) because it never adds the record to the model the first time.

To demonstrate further, in the `setter` part of the computed property, when I put this code:

```
var stats = this.get('controllers.Userstats')
console.log stats
```

the Userstats controller shows all previously existing records, but not newly submitted records!

How come the new record isn't available after I `save()` or `commit()` it???

Thanks :)

**EDIT**

maybe it has something to do with me adding a record to the singular model `App.Userstat` and then when I look for it, I'm searching using the  UserstatsController which is an Array controller???

Comment: Is that all your code? Seems to be missing things? And like intuitivepixel mentioned below there are a few typos (like createRecord missing the closing braces...). Anyway, seems like you never defined the `question` variable that you are passing to your new record? And you are never adding that new record to the `Userstats` controller, so it would never find it when using `findProperty` on its model... and you might have to commit that new `newStat` too?

Comment: Thank you for noticing! I left out important pieces. I must've overwritten them during an edit or something (it was late). I've updated code to reflect my real code and the behavior I experience - namely not being able to find a recently committed record with `.findProperty` on the `Userstats` controller

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a typo, but the computed property is defined the wrong way and should be like this:

```
App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'userstats',
  choice: 'controllers.userstats.choice',
  chosen: function(key, value) {
    ...
  }.property('choice')
  ...
});
```

Inside the `property()` you should also define properties that trigger the computed property if they change. This way if `choice` changes the `chosen` cp will be triggered.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that! There were a few typos in my question. My real code does have a `property()` though. Please see updated code. I renamed `var questionModel` , added `.save()` and `.property()`. These were already in my code so the issue must be elsewhere.